# Do you have an idea how to make this red navigation clickable? (Flexslider)

Tags: css, wordpress, flexslider

I have the problem to make the the red navigation numbers of this site: http://ib.co.at/project/pension-noella clickable?

It should work via CSS. I already tried it with "margin-top" (of #content-area) or a bigger "min-width" (of #flexslider) but those 'solutions' don't work with a flexible amount of numbers.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just give your class `.flexslider` a z-index value:

```
.flexslider {
  z-index: 99;
}
```

It's also good to add your code when you're posting a question. Please [have a look why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Thanks pzin. Thanks for your tip about the source. What was the problem? The positioning?

Comment: Problem was that the `#content-area` was covering your slider.